# jQuery datepicker setdate works only after second click

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an annoying problem. In my case it doesn't matter, but it's quite annoying.

I have radio buttons, which will set the date of the finish date. Here is my code.

```
$('.radios').each(function(i,e){
  $(e).change(function(){
    var id = parseInt($(e).val());
    var start = $('#start').datepicker('getDate');
    if(id == 6)
        start.setDate(start.getDate()+7); 

    $('#finish').datepicker('setDate', start);
    $('#finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate', start);
  });
});
```

So when the .radios value is 6, it will set the date of finish field to a week later. But if other values then it should give the same date as start date.

For example, I choose 13 june on start field, it will set the date to 13 june, but if i choose id=6, then finish date will be 20th of june. However, it stays 20th after i click the others, and it becomes 13 after second select on others.

What do i do wrong in my code?

Comment: Could you please add any `snippet` or `fiddle` replicating the problem?

Comment: please create a working example ( snippet ) of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Set `minDate` option value before `setDate` method calling.

```js
$( "#start, #finish" ).datepicker();
$('.radios').change(function(){
  var id = parseInt($(this).val());
  var start = $('#start').datepicker('getDate');
  if(id == 6) start.setDate(start.getDate()+7); 
  $('#finish').datepicker('option', 'minDate', start);
  $('#finish').datepicker('setDate', start);
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date of start: <input type="text" id="start" value="06/03/2017"></p>
<p>Date of finish: <input type="text" id="finish"></p>
<input type="radio" name="diff" class="radios" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="diff" class="radios" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="diff" class="radios" value="3">3
<input type="radio" name="diff" class="radios" value="4">4
<input type="radio" name="diff" class="radios" value="5">5
<input type="radio" name="diff" class="radios" value="6">6
```